# Can I login into domain under regular Windows 8 (not Pro)?

Tags: windows-8, domain

I going buy a laptop. And a lot of laptops have Windows 8. It's hard to find desirable laptop with Windows 8 Pro version. What I need to do is login to the domain when I get access to our company server.

Can I login to a domain with Windows 8, or will I need Windows 8 Pro?

I don't mean joining the Windows domain, just accessing the shared folders/printers.

Comment: Have you done any research on this?  You need Pro or Enterprise to join the Domain.  http://windows.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows/compare

Comment: @DaveM - Yes, he cannot *join* the domain but he can access shared folders/printers, albeit not as easily as if the PC were joined to the domain.

Comment: @DaveM - The OP states 'I don't mean joining the Windows domain, just accessing the shared folders/printers.'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are differences between the non-Pro and Pro versions of Windows 8/8.1 in respect to domain connectivity.

As has been said, you can connect any version of Windows to a domain to access, say, a shared folder (not "domain join"). The access control here is user credentials. If you have the right access and the right credentials you can access the data. The difference between Pro and non-Pro with file access is that a domain-joined computer (Pro/Enterprise/Ultimate only) (when someone is logged in) is that the user logging in is already presenting authorised credentials to access a shared folder. They won't be asked to enter a username and password. A non-domain-joined computer (where a domain user can't log in to the computer itself) can't provide valid credentials to the shared folder so you receive a popup asking to connect to the folder. You'll get this every restart of the computer or new share you connect to.

Additional things that domain-joined computers benefit from are things like Group Policy.

Higher versions of Windows also have encryption technology BitLocker built-in.

Comment: > You'll get this every restart of the computer or new share you connect to.

Actually you can save credentials in your system.

Comment: Yes, you can, but that's out of the point of the OP's question.

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can. I've check this out on the Windows 8.1 laptop.

I connected to the server via VPN and opened samba folder and system requested for me to log into domain. So I put login "DOMAINNAME\my.username" and password and it works fine.

Comment: Which version of Windows 8 are you using?

Comment: Windodws 8.1 Single Language (SL).

Comment: This is sort of correct.  You really did not fully log in to the domain.  You used a service(s) provided by a server on the domain using credentials that exist on the domain.  You have an account on the domain so this works.

Comment: @DaveM, could you expain me what kind of problems I could face if I will use login only instead joining?

Comment: @Kirby No issues at all usually.  If all you need is access to resources

Comment: @DaveM, got you. Thx!